# Best practice for empty javascript event (e.g. onclick="javascript:;")

Tags: javascript, html

If you want an event or a link to an empty javascript call, there are several ways, of which I can think of:

```
<a href="#">Method 1</a>                    <- Ugh... changes URL in browser
<a href="javascript:;">Method 1</a>         <- My currently preferred method
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Method 1</a>  <- Another approach?
```

What is the best way in terms of cross-browser compatibility and shortness?

Comment: Counterquestion: I see no reasons to put an empty link onto a page?

Comment: Links should... link to something. Even though it seems to be common to add event listeners to links, if it doesn't link to a fallback page if JavaScript is disabled., you should rather use buttons.

Comment: As long as the event calls `preventDefault()` or returns false, `href="#"` doesn't change the browser URL.

Comment: Sometimes I must use this. For instance, I have a clickable h2 that expands a container. I have to add an `a` tag around it for touch optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Jquery solution..

```
$('a.preventDefault').click(function(){
 return false
});

<a href="#" class="preventDefault">Method 1</a>
```

Comment: `return false` also prevents bubbling. Not the best idea.

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev Sure, but putting clickable elements inside `<a>` elements isn't a great idea either

Answer (score 6):

Don't use links if they don't... well, link to anything.

Instead, use a `span` somewhat like this:

```
<span class="spanlink" onclick=something>This is some text</span>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.spanlink {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer; /* Ragnagord's suggestion in comments */
}
```

Comment: I would add `cursor: pointer;` to the css.

Comment: This is not touch-friendly at all. That's the main reason I put links on everything clickable, even if they're not linking to another page.

Comment: @DevilsChild What do you mean by "touch-friendly"?

Comment: When you use a span and touch on it on a touch input device, your finger will select parts of the text, while it doesn't when using a link. Also, IE 10 highlights touched links, not touched spans.

Comment: It's impossible to interact with spans using the keyboard alone, this solution is not accessibility friendly.

Answer (score 2):

How about `button`? I never use anchors if they're not leading anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Using [unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Also, if a link doesn't do anything without Javascript, then a user without Javascript shouldn't even be able to see the link. Add in the link via Javascript.

Comment: Please avoid [link-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).